# Display post and custom post type by user in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a strange problem with my template page author.php
My page display all post and all custom post_type created by the user.

My problem:
If the user creat an article (just one article in total ) in the custom post_type " evenement "
The article not appear in the template page author.php, but now my user creat another article in default post wordpress, two post appear in the template page author.php

My code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['author_name'])) :
$curauth = get_userdatabylogin($author_name);
else :
$curauth = get_userdata(intval($author));
?>   
 <div class="info-diffusion">

    <h1 class="postheader entry-title">Les tutos et astuces de <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h1>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : query_posts('cat=172'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="dif-info-pack">
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); else :?>
    <p><?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?> n'a pas encore créé de tuto et astuce !</p>
    <?php endif;?>
    </div>






    <div class="info-diffusion">
    <h1 class="postheader entry-title">Les vidéos de <?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?></h1>

    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'post_video' ) );


    if (have_posts()) : query_posts( $args ); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="dif-info-pack">
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

    </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); else :?>
    <p><?php echo $curauth->nickname; ?> n'a pas encore posté de vidéo !</p>
    <?php endif;?>
    </div>
```

And the second problem it's for the admin, the information "no posted article" not diplayed

If you have an idea...
Thnak's

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress query_posts() function completely replaces the original query, so:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : query_posts('cat=172'); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

tests to see if the **original** query had any posts and then replaces that query. Probably not what you want.

Instead:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=172&author=' . $curauth->ID); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

gets things in the right order, and displays the "no posted article" message when appropriate. Note that, since you are completely replacing the query you will need to add the author parameter to accomplish what you want.

The same order problem is true of your second query_posts:

```
query_posts( $args ); 
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```